# Get class name of divs on click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get the class name of divs. It works in Chrome, but I have problems with IE5.  If I click on an div element, than it returns `undefined`.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="deneme">
    <div id="container">
        <input id="mytextboxid" class="mytextboxclass" type="textbox" />
        <input id="mybuttonid" class="mybuttonclass" type="button" value="tikla" />
        <div id="innerDivid" class="divElementClass">Div Element</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");

for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].addEventListener) {
        x[i].addEventListener('click', redirect, false);
    } else if (x[i].attachEvent) {
        x[i].attachEvent('on' + 'click', redirect);
    }
}
function redirect() {
    alert(this.className);
}
```

the solution is :

```
function redirect(e){
    var elem, evt = e ? e : event;
    if (evt.srcElement)  elem = evt.srcElement;
    else if (evt.target) elem = evt.target;
    alert(''
            + 'You clicked the following HTML element: \n <'
            + elem.getAttribute('className').toUpperCase()
            + '>'
    )
    return true;
}
```

Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function redirect(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    // alert(target.className);  
    alert(target.getAttribute('class') || target.getAttribute('className'));
}
```

http://jsbin.com/nucofe/1/edit?html,js,output